# Get timestamp in json and convert it in javascipt

Tags: json, timestamp

I get timestamp from https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/malaysia with script:

```
        var getJSON = function(url) {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('get', url, true);
            xhr.responseType = 'json';
            xhr.onload = function() {
              var status = xhr.status;
              if (status == 200) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
              } else {
                reject(status);
              }
            };
            xhr.send();
          });
        };
        
      getJSON('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/malaysia').then(function(data) {
        date1.innerText = data.updated;
        }, function(status) { 
        });
```

Then i try convert it to time by:

```
        function convertTimestamptoTime() { 
            ndate = date1;
  
            dateObj = new Date(ndate * 1000); 
  
            hours = dateObj.getUTCHours(); 

            minutes = dateObj.getUTCMinutes(); 
  

            seconds = dateObj.getUTCSeconds(); 
  
            formattedTime = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + 
                minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + 
                seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0'); 
  
            document.querySelector('.output').textContent = formattedTime; 
        }
```

and display it

```
<div class='output'></div>
```

But it didnt works, whats wrong with it?